# Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList') at window. Onload. Element not in the DOM when the script ran

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, jsx

I converted a page that contains HTML, CSS and JavaScript to a React app. The original website is working fine. But, when I load the React app, I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList') at window. Onload

**It seems like the element I'm trying to get is not in the DOM when the script runs**.

So, I tried 5 following solutions without any positive result:

1. Putting the `defer` attribute on the external scripts.
2. I was thinking of moving the script in script.js, but I can't because I'm using an external script.
3. Using the `type` attribute with the `module` value, but I can't because I'm using an external script.
4. Deferring with event handling, but it's not working.
5. Tried the Event delegation, but is not working neither.

Here is my code:

App.js with some changes to adapt the HTML to JSX:

```
/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
/* eslint-disable no-script-url */
/* eslint-disable jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid */
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      {/* <!-- Start preloader --> */}
      <div id="preloader">
        <div id="ctn-preloader" className="ctn-preloader">
          <div className="animation-preloader">
            <div className="spinner"></div>
            <div className="txt-loading">
              <span data-text-preloader="C" className="letters-loading">
                {' '}
                C{' '}
              </span>

              <span data-text-preloader="H" className="letters-loading">
                {' '}
                H{' '}
              </span>

              <span data-text-preloader="A" className="letters-loading">
                {' '}
                A{' '}
              </span>

              <span data-text-preloader="R" className="letters-loading">
                {' '}
                R{' '}
              </span>

              <span data-text-preloader="G" className="letters-loading">
                {' '}
                G{' '}
              </span>

              <span data-text-preloader="E" className="letters-loading">
                {' '}
                E{' '}
              </span>

              <span data-text-preloader="M" className="letters-loading">
                {' '}
                M{' '}
              </span>

              <span data-text-preloader="E" className="letters-loading">
                {' '}
                E{' '}
              </span>

              <span data-text-preloader="N" className="letters-loading">
                {' '}
                N{' '}
              </span>

              <span data-text-preloader="T" className="letters-loading">
                {' '}
                T{' '}
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="loader-section section-left"></div>
          <div className="loader-section section-right"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      {/* <!-- End preloader --> */}        
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

script.js without any change:

```
'use strict';

// Preloader
const preLoader = function () {
  let preloaderWrapper = document.getElementById('preloader');
  window.onload = () => {
    preloaderWrapper.classList.add('loaded');
  };
};
preLoader();

// getSiblings
var getSiblings = function (elem) {
  const siblings = [];
  let sibling = elem.parentNode.firstChild;
  while (sibling) {
    if (sibling.nodeType === 1 && sibling !== elem) {
      siblings.push(sibling);
    }
    sibling = sibling.nextSibling;
  }
  return siblings;
};

/* Slide Up */
var slideUp = (target, time) => {
  const duration = time ? time : 500;
  target.style.transitionProperty = 'height, margin, padding';
  target.style.transitionDuration = duration + 'ms';
  target.style.boxSizing = 'border-box';
  target.style.height = target.offsetHeight + 'px';
  target.offsetHeight;
  target.style.overflow = 'hidden';
  target.style.height = 0;
  window.setTimeout(() => {
    target.style.display = 'none';
    target.style.removeProperty('height');
    target.style.removeProperty('overflow');
    target.style.removeProperty('transition-duration');
    target.style.removeProperty('transition-property');
  }, duration);
};

/* Slide Down */
var slideDown = (target, time) => {
  const duration = time ? time : 500;
  target.style.removeProperty('display');
  let display = window.getComputedStyle(target).display;
  if (display === 'none') display = 'block';
  target.style.display = display;
  const height = target.offsetHeight;
  target.style.overflow = 'hidden';
  target.style.height = 0;
  target.offsetHeight;
  target.style.boxSizing = 'border-box';
  target.style.transitionProperty = 'height, margin, padding';
  target.style.transitionDuration = duration + 'ms';
  target.style.height = height + 'px';
  window.setTimeout(() => {
    target.style.removeProperty('height');
    target.style.removeProperty('overflow');
    target.style.removeProperty('transition-duration');
    target.style.removeProperty('transition-property');
  }, duration);
};

// Get window top offset
function TopOffset(el) {
  let rect = el.getBoundingClientRect(),
    scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  return { top: rect.top + scrollTop };
}
// Header sticky activation
const headerStickyWrapper = document.querySelector('header');
const headerStickyTarget = document.querySelector('.header__sticky');

if (headerStickyTarget) {
  let headerHeight = headerStickyWrapper.clientHeight;
  window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
    let StickyTargetElement = TopOffset(headerStickyWrapper);
    let TargetElementTopOffset = StickyTargetElement.top;

    if (window.scrollY > TargetElementTopOffset) {
      headerStickyTarget.classList.add('sticky');
    } else {
      headerStickyTarget.classList.remove('sticky');
    }
  });
}

// Back to top
const scrollTop = document.getElementById('scroll__top');
if (scrollTop) {
  scrollTop.addEventListener('click', function () {
    window.scroll({ top: 0, left: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });
  });
  window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
    if (window.scrollY > 300) {
      scrollTop.classList.add('active');
    } else {
      scrollTop.classList.remove('active');
    }
  });
}

// blog swiper column3 activation
var swiper = new Swiper('.blog__swiper--activation', {
  slidesPerView: 3,
  loop: true,
  clickable: true,
  spaceBetween: 30,
  breakpoints: {
    1200: {
      slidesPerView: 3
    },
    992: {
      slidesPerView: 3
    },
    768: {
      slidesPerView: 2,
      spaceBetween: 30
    },
    480: {
      slidesPerView: 2,
      spaceBetween: 20
    },
    0: {
      slidesPerView: 1
    }
  },
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev'
  }
});

// testimonial swiper activation
var swiper = new Swiper('.testimonial__swiper--activation', {
  slidesPerView: 2,
  loop: true,
  clickable: true,
  spaceBetween: 30,
  breakpoints: {
    768: {
      slidesPerView: 2,
      spaceBetween: 30
    },
    576: {
      slidesPerView: 2,
      spaceBetween: 20
    },
    0: {
      slidesPerView: 1
    }
  },
  pagination: {
    clickable: true,
    el: '.swiper-pagination'
  }
});

// testimonial swiper column1 activation
var swiper = new Swiper('.testimonial__swiper--column1', {
  slidesPerView: 1,
  loop: true,
  clickable: true,
  spaceBetween: 30,
  pagination: {
    clickable: true,
    el: '.swiper-pagination'
  }
});

// project swiper activation
var swiper = new Swiper('.project__swiper--activation', {
  slidesPerView: 4,
  loop: true,
  spaceBetween: 30,
  clickable: true,
  roundLengths: true,
  centeredSlides: true,
  breakpoints: {
    1200: {
      slidesPerView: 4,
      spaceBetween: 30
    },
    992: {
      slidesPerView: 3,
      spaceBetween: 25
    },
    768: {
      slidesPerView: 3,
      spaceBetween: 25
    },
    400: {
      slidesPerView: 2,
      spaceBetween: 15
    },
    300: {
      slidesPerView: 1,
      spaceBetween: 15
    },
    0: {
      slidesPerView: 1
    }
  },

  pagination: {
    clickable: true,
    el: '.swiper-pagination'
  }
});

// brand swiper activation
var swiper = new Swiper('.brand__swiper--activation', {
  slidesPerView: 5,
  loop: true,
  spaceBetween: 50,
  clickable: true,
  breakpoints: {
    1366: {
      slidesPerView: 5,
      spaceBetween: 50
    },
    1200: {
      slidesPerView: 5,
      spaceBetween: 40
    },
    992: {
      slidesPerView: 5,
      spaceBetween: 30
    },
    768: {
      slidesPerView: 4,
      spaceBetween: 30
    },
    400: {
      slidesPerView: 3,
      spaceBetween: 20
    },
    200: {
      slidesPerView: 2,
      spaceBetween: 20
    },
    0: {
      slidesPerView: 1
    }
  },

  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev'
  }
});

// related project swiper activation
var swiper = new Swiper('.related__project--swiper', {
  slidesPerView: 4,
  loop: true,
  clickable: true,
  spaceBetween: 30,
  breakpoints: {
    992: {
      slidesPerView: 4
    },
    768: {
      slidesPerView: 3,
      spaceBetween: 30
    },
    576: {
      slidesPerView: 3,
      spaceBetween: 20
    },
    480: {
      slidesPerView: 2,
      spaceBetween: 20
    },
    300: {
      slidesPerView: 2,
      spaceBetween: 15
    },
    0: {
      slidesPerView: 1
    }
  },
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev'
  }
});

// tab activation
const tab = function (wrapper) {
  let tabContainer = document.querySelector(wrapper);
  if (tabContainer) {
    tabContainer.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
      let listItem = evt.target;
      if (listItem.hasAttribute('data-toggle')) {
        let targetId = listItem.dataset.target,
          targetItem = document.querySelector(targetId);
        listItem.parentElement
          .querySelectorAll('[data-toggle="tab"]')
          .forEach(function (list) {
            list.classList.remove('active');
          });
        listItem.classList.add('active');
        targetItem.classList.add('active');
        setTimeout(function () {
          targetItem.classList.add('show');
        }, 150);
        getSiblings(targetItem).forEach(function (pane) {
          pane.classList.remove('show');
          setTimeout(function () {
            pane.classList.remove('active');
          }, 150);
        });
      }
    });
  }
};
// Homepage 1 product tab
tab('.project__tab--one');
tab('.product__tab--one');

// countdown activation
document.querySelectorAll('[data-countdown]').forEach(function (elem) {
  const countDownItem = function (value, label) {
    return `<div class="countdown__item" ${label}"><span class="countdown__number">${value}</span><p class="countdown__text">${label}</p></div>`;
  };
  const date = new Date(elem.getAttribute('data-countdown')).getTime(),
    second = 1000,
    minute = second * 60,
    hour = minute * 60,
    day = hour * 24;
  const countDownInterval = setInterval(function () {
    let currentTime = new Date().getTime(),
      timeDistance = date - currentTime,
      daysValue = Math.floor(timeDistance / day),
      hoursValue = Math.floor((timeDistance % day) / hour),
      minutesValue = Math.floor((timeDistance % hour) / minute),
      secondsValue = Math.floor((timeDistance % minute) / second);

    elem.innerHTML =
      countDownItem(daysValue, 'days') +
      countDownItem(hoursValue, 'hrs') +
      countDownItem(minutesValue, 'mins') +
      countDownItem(secondsValue, 'secs');

    if (timeDistance < 0) clearInterval(countDownInterval);
  }, 1000);
});

// adding & removing class function
const activeClassAction = function (toggle, target) {
  const to = document.querySelector(toggle),
    ta = document.querySelector(target);
  if (to && ta) {
    to.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      let triggerItem = e.target;
      if (triggerItem.classList.contains('active')) {
        triggerItem.classList.remove('active');
        ta.classList.remove('active');
      } else {
        triggerItem.classList.add('active');
        ta.classList.add('active');
      }
    });
    document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
      if (
        !event.target.closest(toggle) &&
        !event.target.classList.contains(toggle.replace(/\./, ''))
      ) {
        if (
          !event.target.closest(target) &&
          !event.target.classList.contains(target.replace(/\./, ''))
        ) {
          to.classList.remove('active');
          ta.classList.remove('active');
        }
      }
    });
  }
};

activeClassAction('.account__currency--link', '.dropdown__currency');
activeClassAction('.language__switcher', '.dropdown__language');
activeClassAction(
  '.offcanvas__language--switcher',
  '.offcanvas__dropdown--language'
);
activeClassAction(
  '.offcanvas__account--currency__menu',
  '.offcanvas__account--currency__submenu'
);
activeClassAction('.footer__language--link', '.footer__dropdown--language');
activeClassAction('.footer__currency--link', '.footer__dropdown--currency');

// OffCanvas Sidebar Activation
function offcanvsSidebar(openTrigger, closeTrigger, wrapper) {
  let OpenTriggerprimary__btn = document.querySelectorAll(openTrigger);
  let closeTriggerprimary__btn = document.querySelector(closeTrigger);
  let WrapperSidebar = document.querySelector(wrapper);
  let wrapperOverlay = wrapper.replace('.', '');

  function handleBodyClass(evt) {
    let eventTarget = evt.target;
    if (!eventTarget.closest(wrapper) && !eventTarget.closest(openTrigger)) {
      WrapperSidebar.classList.remove('active');
      document
        .querySelector('body')
        .classList.remove(`${wrapperOverlay}_active`);
    }
  }
  if (OpenTriggerprimary__btn && WrapperSidebar) {
    OpenTriggerprimary__btn.forEach(function (singleItem) {
      singleItem.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        if (e.target.dataset.offcanvas != undefined) {
          WrapperSidebar.classList.add('active');
          document
            .querySelector('body')
            .classList.add(`${wrapperOverlay}_active`);
          document.body.addEventListener('click', handleBodyClass.bind(this));
        }
      });
    });
  }

  if (closeTriggerprimary__btn && WrapperSidebar) {
    closeTriggerprimary__btn.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
      if (e.target.dataset.offcanvas != undefined) {
        WrapperSidebar.classList.remove('active');
        document
          .querySelector('body')
          .classList.remove(`${wrapperOverlay}_active`);
        document.body.removeEventListener('click', handleBodyClass.bind(this));
      }
    });
  }
}

// Mini Cart
offcanvsSidebar(
  '.minicart__open--btn',
  '.minicart__close--btn',
  '.offCanvas__minicart'
);

// Search Bar
offcanvsSidebar(
  '.search__open--btn',
  '.predictive__search--close__btn',
  '.predictive__search--box'
);

// Offcanvas filter sidebar
offcanvsSidebar(
  '.widget__filter--btn',
  '.offcanvas__filter--close',
  '.offcanvas__filter--sidebar'
);

/* Offcanvas Mobile Menu Function */
const offcanvasHeader = function () {
  const offcanvasOpen = document.querySelector(
      '.offcanvas__header--menu__open--btn'
    ),
    offcanvasClose = document.querySelector('.offcanvas__close--btn'),
    offcanvasHeader = document.querySelector('.offcanvas-header'),
    offcanvasMenu = document.querySelector('.offcanvas__menu'),
    body = document.querySelector('body');
  /* Offcanvas SubMenu Toggle */
  if (offcanvasMenu) {
    offcanvasMenu
      .querySelectorAll('.offcanvas__sub_menu')
      .forEach(function (ul) {
        const subMenuToggle = document.createElement('button');
        subMenuToggle.classList.add('offcanvas__sub_menu_toggle');
        ul.parentNode.appendChild(subMenuToggle);
      });
  }
  /* Open/Close Menu On Click Toggle Button */
  if (offcanvasOpen) {
    offcanvasOpen.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      if (e.target.dataset.offcanvas != undefined) {
        offcanvasHeader.classList.add('open');
        body.classList.add('mobile_menu_open');
      }
    });
  }
  if (offcanvasClose) {
    offcanvasClose.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      if (e.target.dataset.offcanvas != undefined) {
        offcanvasHeader.classList.remove('open');
        body.classList.remove('mobile_menu_open');
      }
    });
  }

  /* Mobile submenu slideToggle Activation */
  let mobileMenuWrapper = document.querySelector('.offcanvas__menu_ul');
  if (mobileMenuWrapper) {
    mobileMenuWrapper.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
      let targetElement = e.target;
      if (targetElement.classList.contains('offcanvas__sub_menu_toggle')) {
        const parent = targetElement.parentElement;
        if (parent.classList.contains('active')) {
          targetElement.classList.remove('active');
          parent.classList.remove('active');
          parent
            .querySelectorAll('.offcanvas__sub_menu')
            .forEach(function (subMenu) {
              subMenu.parentElement.classList.remove('active');
              subMenu.nextElementSibling.classList.remove('active');
              slideUp(subMenu);
            });
        } else {
          targetElement.classList.add('active');
          parent.classList.add('active');
          slideDown(targetElement.previousElementSibling);
          getSiblings(parent).forEach(function (item) {
            item.classList.remove('active');
            item
              .querySelectorAll('.offcanvas__sub_menu')
              .forEach(function (subMenu) {
                subMenu.parentElement.classList.remove('active');
                subMenu.nextElementSibling.classList.remove('active');
                slideUp(subMenu);
              });
          });
        }
      }
    });
  }

  if (offcanvasHeader) {
    document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
      if (
        !event.target.closest('.offcanvas__header--menu__open--btn') &&
        !event.target.classList.contains(
          '.offcanvas__header--menu__open--btn'.replace(/\./, '')
        )
      ) {
        if (
          !event.target.closest('.offcanvas-header') &&
          !event.target.classList.contains(
            '.offcanvas-header'.replace(/\./, '')
          )
        ) {
          offcanvasHeader.classList.remove('open');
          body.classList.remove('mobile_menu_open');
        }
      }
    });
  }

  /* Remove Mobile Menu Open Class & Hide Mobile Menu When Window Width in More Than 991 */
  if (offcanvasHeader) {
    window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
      if (window.outerWidth >= 992) {
        offcanvasHeader.classList.remove('open');
        body.classList.remove('mobile_menu_open');
      }
    });
  }
};
/* Mobile Menu Active */
offcanvasHeader();

// Increment & Decrement Qunatity Button
const quantityWrapper = document.querySelectorAll('.quantity__box');
if (quantityWrapper) {
  quantityWrapper.forEach(function (singleItem) {
    let increaseButton = singleItem.querySelector('.increase');
    let decreaseButton = singleItem.querySelector('.decrease');

    increaseButton.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
      let input = e.target.previousElementSibling.children[0];
      if (input.dataset.counter != undefined) {
        let value = parseInt(input.value, 10);
        value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
        value++;
        input.value = value;
      }
    });

    decreaseButton.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
      let input = e.target.nextElementSibling.children[0];
      if (input.dataset.counter != undefined) {
        let value = parseInt(input.value, 10);
        value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
        value < 1 ? (value = 1) : '';
        value--;
        input.value = value;
      }
    });
  });
}

// Modal JS
const openEls = document.querySelectorAll('[data-open]');
const closeEls = document.querySelectorAll('[data-close]');
const isVisible = 'is-visible';
for (const el of openEls) {
  el.addEventListener('click', function () {
    const modalId = this.dataset.open;
    document.getElementById(modalId).classList.add(isVisible);
  });
}
for (const el of closeEls) {
  el.addEventListener('click', function () {
    this.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.classList.remove(isVisible);
  });
}
document.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target == document.querySelector('.modal.is-visible')) {
    document.querySelector('.modal.is-visible').classList.remove(isVisible);
  }
});
document.addEventListener('keyup', e => {
  if (e.key == 'Escape' && document.querySelector('.modal.is-visible')) {
    document.querySelector('.modal.is-visible').classList.remove(isVisible);
  }
});

// Accordion
function customAccordion(accordionWrapper, singleItem, accordionBody) {
  let accoridonButtons = document.querySelectorAll(accordionWrapper);
  accoridonButtons.forEach(function (item) {
    item.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
      let itemTarget = evt.target;
      if (
        itemTarget.classList.contains('accordion__items--button') ||
        itemTarget.classList.contains('widget__categories--menu__label')
      ) {
        let singleAccordionWrapper = itemTarget.closest(singleItem),
          singleAccordionBody =
            singleAccordionWrapper.querySelector(accordionBody);
        if (singleAccordionWrapper.classList.contains('active')) {
          singleAccordionWrapper.classList.remove('active');
          slideUp(singleAccordionBody);
        } else {
          singleAccordionWrapper.classList.add('active');
          slideDown(singleAccordionBody);
          getSiblings(singleAccordionWrapper).forEach(function (item) {
            let sibllingSingleAccordionBody = item.querySelector(accordionBody);
            item.classList.remove('active');
            slideUp(sibllingSingleAccordionBody);
          });
        }
      }
    });
  });
}
customAccordion(
  '.accordion__container',
  '.accordion__items',
  '.accordion__items--body'
);

customAccordion(
  '.widget__categories--menu',
  '.widget__categories--menu__list',
  '.widget__categories--sub__menu'
);

// footer widget js
let accordion = true;
const footerWidgetAccordion = function () {
  accordion = false;
  let footerWidgetContainer = document.querySelector('.main__footer');
  footerWidgetContainer.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
    let singleItemTarget = evt.target;
    if (singleItemTarget.classList.contains('footer__widget--button')) {
      const footerWidget = singleItemTarget.closest('.footer__widget'),
        footerWidgetInner = footerWidget.querySelector(
          '.footer__widget--inner'
        );
      if (footerWidget.classList.contains('active')) {
        footerWidget.classList.remove('active');
        slideUp(footerWidgetInner);
      } else {
        footerWidget.classList.add('active');
        slideDown(footerWidgetInner);
        getSiblings(footerWidget).forEach(function (item) {
          const footerWidgetInner = item.querySelector(
            '.footer__widget--inner'
          );

          item.classList.remove('active');
          slideUp(footerWidgetInner);
        });
      }
    }
  });
};

window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  if (accordion) {
    footerWidgetAccordion();
  }
});
window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
  document.querySelectorAll('.footer__widget').forEach(function (item) {
    if (window.outerWidth >= 768) {
      item.classList.remove('active');
      item.querySelector('.footer__widget--inner').style.display = '';
    }
  });
  if (accordion) {
    footerWidgetAccordion();
  }
});

// lightbox Activation
const customLightboxHTML = `<div id="glightbox-body" class="glightbox-container">
    <div class="gloader visible"></div>
    <div class="goverlay"></div>
    <div class="gcontainer">
    <div id="glightbox-slider" class="gslider"></div>
    <button class="gnext gbtn" tabindex="0" aria-label="Next" data-customattribute="example">{nextSVG}</button>
    <button class="gprev gbtn" tabindex="1" aria-label="Previous">{prevSVG}</button>
    <button class="gclose gbtn" tabindex="2" aria-label="Close">{closeSVG}</button>
    </div>
    </div>`;
const lightbox = GLightbox({
  touchNavigation: true,
  lightboxHTML: customLightboxHTML,
  loop: true
});

// CounterUp Activation
const wrapper = document.getElementById('funfactId');
if (wrapper) {
  const counters = wrapper.querySelectorAll('.js-counter');
  const duration = 400;

  let isCounted = false;
  document.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
    const wrapperPos = wrapper.offsetTop - window.innerHeight;
    if (!isCounted && window.scrollY > wrapperPos) {
      counters.forEach(counter => {
        const countTo = counter.dataset.count;

        const countPerMs = countTo / duration;

        let currentCount = 0;
        const countInterval = setInterval(function () {
          if (currentCount >= countTo) {
            clearInterval(countInterval);
          }
          counter.textContent = Math.round(currentCount);
          currentCount = currentCount + countPerMs;
        }, 1);
      });
      isCounted = true;
    }
  });
}
```

Anyone has the correct solution?

Comment: If you use DOM methods directly chances are your using React wrong.  But if you really do need to do it, you need to use `useRef` and `useEffect`

Comment: I see. That might be the issue. However, how can I use `useRef` and `useEffect` in this code that was only HTML, CSS and JavaScript?

Comment: To access the DOM react creates you use  https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useRef#manipulating-the-dom-with-a-ref  to do something with the DOM when mounted use https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useEffect

Comment: I tried to set up `useRef` as follows: function App() {
  const inputRef = useRef(null);
  return (<input ref={inputRef} />)(
    <div>
      {/* <!-- Start preloader --> */}

Comment: I am not able to use `useRef` in this code. Besides that, I do not think that `useEffect` is appropriated to solve this issue. Or, I might not manage it properly.